# How do I write a stim diagram to a file?

Tags: stim

I made an svg diagram from a stim circuit:

```python
import stim
circuit = stim.Circuit("""
    H 0
    CX 0 1
    M 0 1
""")
diagram = circuit.diagram("timeline-svg")
display(diagram)
```

> [image]

I tried to write the diagram to a file, but I got an error:

```python
with open('diagram.svg', 'w') as f:
    f.write(diagram)
```

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not stim._DiagramHelper
```

How do I save the diagram to an SVG image file?

Comment: Got asked this outside of QCSE. Copying it here for posterity.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```python
with open('diagram.svg', 'w') as f:
    print(diagram, file=f)
```

Or this:

```python
with open('diagram.svg', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(diagram))
```

The `stim._DiagramHelper` class has a `__str__` method that returns the contents of the SVG file. The diagram method could just return a string... but then tools like Jupyter notebook wouldn't display it as an image.